# How to return exactly the highest value from a Hamming-distance

Tags: java

I want to calculate the hamming-distance for 2 different bit-strings.

I have done most of the code in Java, but I don't know how I can return the highest number ( in this case 4).

I have done bit-comparison using the XOR (^) between both sequences and also tried to get the right answer by using for-loops, followed by System.out.println(Long.bitCount(code.get(y) ^ code.get(x)));

```java
import java.util.List;

class Solution {

  public static long calculate(List<Long> code) {

    long sequenceX = Long.parseLong("00000000", 2);
    long sequenceY = Long.parseLong("10101010", 2);

    System.out.println(Long.bitCount(sequenceX ^ sequenceY));

    for (int x = 0; x < code.size(); x++) {
      code.get(x);

      for (int y = 0; y < code.size(); y++) {
        code.get(y);
        System.out.println(Long.bitCount(code.get(y) ^ code.get(x)));        
      }        
    }

    if (sequenceX == sequenceY){
      return 0;
    }

    return code.size();  
  }
}
```

Expected result is 4, but I receive a list of numbers in the console section ranging from 0 to 8.

Comment: How are you calling this? Are you ever using the returned value?

Comment: Well, that is something I don't know how to implement

Comment: @Alfredo8767 What are you want to do with the list `code` and how is it related to your expected result `4`? And what are these single `code.get(...)` lines doing? Please [edit] your question to add additional information about your problem and what you want to do.

Comment: @Alfredo8767 Please edit your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show the output you get and describe what the output/result should be instead.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to clear some unrelated stuff:

```
public static long calculate(List<Long> code) {

    long sequenceX = Long.parseLong("00000000", 2);
    long sequenceY = Long.parseLong("10101010", 2);

    long answer = Long.bitCount(sequenceX ^ sequenceY);
    System.out.println("Done:  "+ answer);

    return answer;  
}
```